How to bake metaballs animation for UE?
I want to make a simple animation using metaballs in blender and import it into Unreal Engine. But since metaballs will only work in blender, apparently I need to bake the animation somehow.
If I can convert metaballs to mesh, can I convert animated metaballs to shapekeys? Or is there any alternative solution?

I would try alembic
